# Vite is not loading CSS codes that are inside of VUE components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

My application is built with Laravel, and Inertia.js with Vue. I am using Vite to bundle the frontend files.

Generally, the application works fine, however, when I put the application inside a subdirectory, Vite does not load the CSS codes that are inside the .vue files or components.

As a result, it shows a blank page when I visit the page URL example.com/subdirectory/login

The browser console shows the following:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to preload CSS for /build/assets/Login.a0d488b1.css
d http://example.com/subdirectory/build/assets/app.6486bb89.js:1

In this case, I am trying to visit the Login page/component. However, it is failing to load the **Login.a0d488b1.css** file because it is missing the **subdirectory** name at the beginning of its path.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

My vite.config.js file looks like the following:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [
       laravel({
           input : [
               // 'resources/sass/app.scss',
               'resources/js/app.js',

               // website
               'resources/sass/website/theme.scss',
               'resources/js/website/main.js',

               
           ],
           refresh: [{
               //paths: ['resources/**'],
               paths: ['resources/js/**', 'resources/sass/**'],
               config: { delay: 300 }
           }],
       }),    
       
       vue({
           template: {
               transformAssetUrls: {
                   base: null,
                   includeAbsolute: false,
               },
           },
       }),
   ],
   resolve: {
       alias: {
           // '@': '/resources/js',
           'ziggy': path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
           'ziggy-vue' : path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/vue'),            
       }
   }
});
```